# CasperJS Hangs When Called From Specific PHP Gearman Init

Tags: php, casperjs, supervisord, gearman

I need to run a casperJS script to be started from Gearman, via PHP. All works wonderfully when I start the Gearman worker from the CLI. But if I start the Gearman worker automatically via something like supervisord, casperJS will cause PhantomJS to hang infinitely at 99% CPU. Even a simple 'casperjs --version' will cause PhantomJS to hang - but only when started from anywhere but the CLI like so: `/usr/bin/php /var/www/xmweb/gearman_client_tests/casperTest.php` This is all happening on a vagrant VM running Debian Wheezy.

I'm looking for anywhere to troubleshoot why PHPs/Gearmans spawn of casperJS will only work when called from the CLI; why the complete hang of phantomJS otherwise? If it were a permissions or environment thing, why would "phantomjs --version" work but not "casperjs --version"?

```
<?php
/**
 * The Gearman Worker script
 */ 
$worker= new GearmanWorker();
$worker->addServer();
$worker->addFunction("LayoutbooksAssembler", "sendToCasper");
while ($worker->work());

function sendToCasper($job) {
    echo "whoami you ask? ";
    $processUser = posix_getpwuid(posix_geteuid());
    print $processUser['name'];
    echo "!\r\n\r\n";
    $jobParams = (array) json_decode($job->workload());
    exec("phantomjs --version",$output);
    var_dump($output); //got the phantomjs version (2.1)

    //everything thus far is rendered to screen or logged just finewhen worker is initiated via CLI *or* supervisord
    //but if started from supervisord, the casperjs process below hangs (phantomjs takes 99% CPU until killed) and nothing in a casper script runs
    exec("casperjs --version",$moreOutput)
    var_dump($moreOutput); //will never get here if gearman worker is started from anything but CLI

}
```

supervisord.conf:

```
[program:casperWorker]
command=/usr/bin/php /var/www/xmweb/gearman_client_tests/casperTest.php
process_name=casperWorker
numprocs=1
user=vagrant
environment=GEARMAN_USER="vagrant"
stopsignal=KILL
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stdout_logfile=/home/vagrant/gearmanLogs/casper.log
stderr_logfile=/home/vagrant/gearmanLogs/casper_errors.log
```

This works fine, if called via direct url (noProb.php):

```
<?php
exec("casperjs --version",$newOutput);
var_dump($newOutput);
```

Comment: FWIW I gave up on this after too much time spinning wheels, and wrote the GearmanWorker in NodeJS, managed by pm2 to keep it up / keep a worker listening.